# why sometimes voice not received on video call by tokbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, streaming, video-streaming, opentok, tokbox

I am developing one specific application by ruby on rails where I need feature like video call.For video call, I have used the tokbox API where I got succeed but sometimes my application failed to receive voice from end to end user.

Is there any possibilities for this scenario? I hope its happening due to the bandwidth problem.

What is the criteria for this case? Please let me know your comments.